# Constant pressure process with out a lid AND diffusion of gas

Tags: thermodynamics

I've been reading thermodynamics basics for chemistry [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/thermodynamics-chemistry/internal-energy-sal/a/pressure-volume-work).

Consider a *constant pressure* process where the gas is **sealed** :

[image]

Here the work done by the system is $p_{ext}(V_f-V_i)$. So far so good. Khan academy link says that a process done *with out a lid* is also a constant pressure process. I don't get this. Wouldn't the gas simply escape from the container since the lid is open ? Also how to calculate the change in volume ? Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a link to the Khan presentation?

Comment: In ***chemistry***, we are generally not concerned with the gases. We are only concerned with the heat changes. So we say that the heat added to the system was added a constant pressure of 1 atm. Please provide a link though.

Comment: Hey @BobD I did provide the link above. Here it is again : 
https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/thermodynamics-chemistry/internal-energy-sal/a/pressure-volume-work

Comment: @rsadhvika They involve gases. But we are generally only concerned with the heat changes in the reaction and thus finding the enthalpy of the reaction.

Comment: Okay Ty, I think I get it now :)  I guess we can measure the enthalpy by measuring the temperature and ignore the gas particles that get diffused into the  surroundings ? @HarshitJoshi

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chemistry, we are generally not concerned with the gases. We are only concerned with the heat changes. So we say that the heat added to the system was added a constant pressure of 1 atm. we are generally only concerned with the heat changes in the reaction and thus finding the enthalpy of the reaction.